# More visible space in Midnight Commander for command lines

Tags: linux, midnight-commander

I want more space as shown here:

[image]

How can I get it?

UPD: There is FAR on the screenshot, but seems mc support this feature too: F9 > Options > Layout > Console output. But it do not works: [upstream bug](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3655), [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mc/+bug/1738535).

Comment: Sorry, guy, it's not my desktop, I find picture in internet and cut monitor screen. Before I did not know, that it's really available in mc.

Comment: It looks like [FAR manager](https://www.farmanager.com/screenshots.php?l=en), not midnight commander.

Comment: Oh my god, then sorry.

Comment: Update question text.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the space if you hit Ctrl-O in Midnight Commander. That hides the panes. When you need them back, hit Ctrl-O again.